# How to style form submit button in CSS?

Tags: html, css, forms, menu

I have a problem and I cannot fix it.

I have a website, with a menu on top that looks nice.
If you hover above the menu it highlights, it is not JavScript but HTML 1 strict (it must be this).

I made a from like this one:

```
<form action="masterpage.cgi" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="test" value="hoi">
<input type="submit" value="opgave2" />
</form>
```

this works perfectly, but it looks ugly.
I want to use my top nav links( or i want it to be buttons that look the same) to be the submit button. How can i do this ?

Menu links :

```
<li><a href="../Nieuws/Nieuws.html">Nieuws </a></li>
```

current css:

```
ul.topNav  {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:960px;
}
.topNav li{
     float:left;
     display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Do little bit research https://www.google.ge/?gws_rd=cr&ei=rpuYUp2-DYaJ5ATQqYCQCQ#q=buttons+in+css

Comment: Do you want your links to look like buttons or should the buttons look like links? Maybe this [site](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css3-gradient-buttons) can give you an idea how to style your buttons, the same can be used for links, just make them `display: inline-block;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more control over the style of your submit button, use the button tag as so:

HTML

```
<form action="masterpage.cgi" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="hoi">
    <button type="submit" name="submit">opgave2</button>
</form>
```

CSS - In this case I've styled it to appear like a link. (Not the best idea, just an example)

```
ul.topNav {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:960px
}   
.topNav li {
    float:left;
    display:inline-block
}   
button {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    color:#00C;
    font-size:24px
}   
button:hover {
    text-decoration:underline;
    cursor:pointer
}
```